# Prove that $A^* = -A$ for normal operator in Euclidean space.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory

Let $A$ -- normal operator in Euclidean space such that $$A^2 = -id$$

The question is to prove that in this case $$A^* = -A$$

Here's what I could find about this problem:

We know that $A^*A = AA^*$. We can multiply the equality on the right by $A$ and get $-A^* = AA^*A$ and seems like we only have to prove this equality.
But what we know about $AA^*A$?

Also I think we can say $-A^*A = AA^*$ and intuitively understand that the equality that we want to get is satisfied.

But what is the main idea I miss to prove this? How can we use that $A$ is a Euclidean space?

Comment: $(iA)^2 = I$, maybe you can use that?

Comment: The final sentence is confused. Nobody wants to use that a normal operator is an Euclidean space, that makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Complexify the space, the inner product and the normal operator, so that you have the same question (with $A^*$ the Hermitian adjoint) in a complex inner product space; the result there will imply the result for the Euclidean space by restriction to the original (real) vector space.

Now saying that $A$ is normal (so it commutes with $A^*$) is equivalent to saying that its Hermitian part $\frac12(A+A^*)$ and its anti-Hermitian part $\frac12(A-A^*)$ commute with each other. Both Hermitian and anti-Hermitian operators are diagonalisable (with respect to an orthonormal basis), so these two are *simultaneously* diagonalisable (with respect to an orthonormal basis). By choosing such a basis of simultaneous diagonalisation, we can rephrase the question in terms of complex *diagonal* matrices. But such matrices satisfy $A^2=-I$ only if all diagonal entries are either $\mathbf{i}$ or $-\mathbf{i}$, and this implies they are anti-Hermitian. But then $A$ was an anti-Hermitian operator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible approach. Consider $(I+A^\ast A)^2$. Note that $A^\ast A$ is positive semidefinite, so that $I+A^\ast A$ is positive definite. On a Euclidean space, strictly positive operators are invertible.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If $A^* = -A$ is satisfied then operator $A$ can be expressed by $A =  i B$ (similar for conjugated one $A^*=-iB$), where $B$ is *real* operator and $i$ is imaginary unit.